# OutputDebugString with both WinDbg and DbgView

Tags: c, windbg, wm-copydata, debugview, outputdebugstring

With [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) is simple:  I clear its output window with "DBGVIEWCLEAR" (in [OutputDebugString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw), **ODS**), and then I show some 10 lines of info. I do this with a timer, 10 times per second.

But, while using [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools), DebugView doesn't get any output from **ODS**.

Q1: can WinDbg ignore / pass-through **ODS**, so that DebugView can catch it?

Or, maybe I could use WinDbg only: first, I'd have to setup `.ocommand WINDBGCMD`, then I could clear its output window with `OutputDebugString("WINDBGCMD .cls;g");`... but that fails with WinDbg telling me "Syntax error in ' .cls;g'".

Strange, but if I use `OutputDebugString("WINDBGCMD .echo\"Hello\";g");` that works just fine.

Q2: how to clear the output window of WinDbg (using **ODS**)?

Q3: finally, it would be better if I could use [WM_COPYDATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata) with some external APP that would be able to clear its output window and show my 10 lines of info - is there such an APP? Maybe [TraceTool](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5498/TraceTool-The-Swiss-Army-Knife-of-Trace), but that looks complicated. Also, it looks as it requires C++, not C.

Note: before **ODS**, I used to simply [TextOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-textoutw) on the desktop. That worked just fine, but visually interfered.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-cls--clear-screen-

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by using [DebugView++](https://github.com/CobaltFusion/DebugViewPP)

DebugView++ can receive debug string using SendMessage:

```
HWND debugviewpp = FindWindow(NULL, "[Capture Win32] - DebugView++");
SendMessage(debugviewpp, EM_REPLACESEL, GetCurrentProcessId(), (LPARAM) "Text 2 send");
```

Thus, WinDbg is out of the way.